# jquery ui.timepickr shows {z} instead of am or pm

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-timepicker

For example: 03:00 {z} instead of 03:00 am while moving mouse around its menu (and after click too).

I use this timepickr: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/UiTimepickr

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timepicker').timepickr({convention: 12, suffix: ['am', 'pm']});
});
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".timepicker").timepickr({
            convention: 12,
            format12: "{h:02.d}:{m:02.d} {z:s}"
        });
```

or

```
$(".timepicker").timepickr({
            convention: 12,
            format12: "{h:02.d}:{m:02.d} {z}"
        });
```

This should get you